# Is polynomial algebra the only minimal dense subalgebra of $C^{\infty}(U)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $U$ be connected open set of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Consider $C^{\infty}(U)$ with sup norm, we said $A\subset C^{\infty}(U)$ is a minimal dense subalgebra of $C^{\infty}(U)$ if and only if any subalgebra contain in $A$ is not dense in $C^{\infty}(U)$. I want to ask are the polynomial algebra of $U$, either with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$\ $\mathbb{Q}$, the only two minimal dense subalgebra of $C^{\infty}(U)$?

Comment: I think you need $U$ to be bounded and probably you want to consider $C^\infty(\overline{U})$. Otherwise I do not see why polynomials should be dense, respectively what kind of topology you want to put.

Answer (score 1):

For proper U, polynomials in even powers or trigonometric polynomials i.e. span of ${e^{ikt}}$ will do. Also, if $U=[a,b]\subset (0,1)$ then polynomials with integer coefficients are good.

Comment: Is set of polynomial of even powers dense?

Comment: Yes, as long as $\sum \frac{1}{n_{k}}$ is divergent polynomials in ${n_{k}}$ are dense in $C[0,1]$. This is so called Muntz-Sasz theorem. Though, in case of even powers it is just a matter of a substitution $x=t^{2}$.

Comment: @Salcio, I do not think polynomials in even powers are dense since they agree on $x$ and $-x$.

Comment: @Salcio, the Muntz-Sasz is not too relevant here since the set of polynomials it refers to is not always an algebra.  When it is, the series always diverges.

Comment: As I said above "for proper U". In case of polynomials in even powers they work on $C[0,1]$. If you want to use $C[-1,1]$ you may use powers divisible by 3. Lastly, see my comments about Muntz-Sasz in the first post.

Comment: The term "proper" has a technical meaning as in "proper subset", so I guess you meant "appropriate", right?  Didn't find your comments in the "first post".  Could you provide a link?

Answer (score 1):

In orded for the sup norm  to be well defined for polinomials one needs to assume that $U$ is bounded.  On the other hand the connectedness of $U$ seems irrelevant here.

In that case, the algebra of polynomials is dense in the sup norm by Stone-Weierstrass' Theorem, but it is not minimal.  The reason is that, for every *odd* number $k$, the set of polynomials of the form
$$
  p(x) = \sum_{n=0}^d a_n x^{kn},
  $$
is dense (again by Stone-Weierstrass) and it is a proper subalgebra of the polinomial algebra (this works also if $k$ is even and $U\subseteq (0,+\infty)$).

Comment: Let $k=3$, how do $p(x)$ converge to x?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem?   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem,_real_version

Comment: So in conclusion, there are no minimal dense subalgebra when $U$ is bounded,  since $k$ can be as large as we want, and it form a decreasing chain of subalgebra,  which does not become stationary.

Comment: My argument only shows that the polinomial algebra is not minimaly dense, but I am not sure if some other algebra might have this property.